# Adobe XD - can't grab green box of overly transition

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm trying to do an overlay graphic that shows up when an element is click. to do that i'm drawing a transition arrow between two artboards. The main artboard is the design of the page itself, the second artboard is a little edit button popover. when i go to drag the position of the overlaid element, it isn't grabbable. it shows up as a green box, but i can't click it.

how do I position that element for the overlay transition?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try zooming in. If you have to zoom in to the point where you can't see where you want to put the overlay you can always just move it part of the way then pan your screen.

Comment: that was it, just zoom into the green overlay until you see the move icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the viewport height down. [image]